# how to prevent duplicate columns in inner join with multiple select clauses

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select * from
         (select date, gen_city_id, min(temp) as min_temp, max(temp) as max_temp from current_weather group by date, gen_city_id order by date) cw
         inner join
         (select gen_city_id, forecast_date, array_agg(temp) from forecast where forecast_date < current_date group by gen_city_id, forecast_date) f
         on cw.gen_city_id = f.gen_city_id and cw.date = f.forecast_date;
```

The above query works, however the `gen_city_id` and `date/forecast_date` columns are selected from both the tables. In my result set how do I prevent duplicate columns from both the tables ?

If I try removing the columns from the select cause of any one of the tables, then the query errors out.

Comment: Don't use `select *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query in this way. You can specify which fields you want to obtain in the resultset:

```
select cw.*,f.temp from
         (select date, gen_city_id, min(temp) as min_temp, max(temp) as max_temp from current_weather group by date, gen_city_id order by date) cw
         inner join
         (select gen_city_id, forecast_date, array_agg(temp) temp from forecast where forecast_date < current_date group by gen_city_id, forecast_date) f
         on cw.gen_city_id = f.gen_city_id and cw.date = f.forecast_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use the `using` clause:

```
select *
from (select date, gen_city_id, min(temp) as min_temp, max(temp) as max_temp
      from current_weather
      group by date, gen_city_id order by date
     ) cw join
     (select gen_city_id, forecast_date as date, array_agg(temp)
      from forecast
      where forecast_date < current_date
      group by gen_city_id, forecast_date
     ) f
     using (gen_city_id, date) ;
```

This removes the duplicate columns included in the `using` clause.

In general, though, I recommend listing out all the columns separately.